# Add item to list in txt file using json (python)

Tags: python, json, list, file, addition

I've only started python very recently and have a few questions about using json for adding items to a list in a file.

My txt file contains the following string:
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
I would like to use `json` to add a item to the list. Is there a way of doing this without loading the file?

```
import json
testfile = open('testfile, 'a')
list3 = [9,10,11,12]
json.dump(list3, testfile)
```

This would result in *[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]][9,10,11,12]* but i would like to have *[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]* write in the file.

Could I use `extend` for this purpose?
And if I do it like this will this affect the read speed using `json.read`?
I am required to use `json` because the list I will add each time are very big.

Hope anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mu the performance hit of reading the entire file into memory with the json library might not be that small. It sounds like SecondLemon may be using a very big json file. If you have 10GB of JSON log data, reading that into memory might not be a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load file content -->> do operation on content -->> again dump file content.

1. Read file content.
2. Loads file content by `json.loads()` which return list.
3. Append New list.
4. Save dump file by `json.dump()`

code:

```
import json
testfile = '/home/vivek/Desktop/input12.txt'

with open(testfile ) as fp:
    content = fp.read()

value = json.loads(content)

list3 = [9,10,11,12]
value.append(list3)

with open(testfile, "wb" ) as fp:
    json.dump(value, fp)
```

output:
File content:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Nice. Very similar to others but a bit more easy for me to understand. I was confused about 'json.loads' because I thought it would already open the file. As I understand it now you just open the file. Stores whatever would be in it as 'content' and then translate it using 'son.loads'. Nice to learn things :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you will need to read this array while the file is still being amended.

I would suggest omitting the array binder '[ .... ]' such that you now have a csv-like file, which you can just keep writing data to.

If it must be loaded into a specific format, you can write a simple parser to re-construct the desired array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the JSON in a file without loading it. You have to do something like this:

```
import json

with open('testfile', 'r') as f:
    json_list = json.loads(r.read())

list3 = [9,10,11,12]
json_list.append(list3)

with open('testfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(json_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to do this without reading the file, because the append mode for file IO always appends data to the end of the file, which means you will always append data outside of your closing array bracket.

However if your goal is to avoid reading the whole file into memory at once, you could use an incremental parser, either by writing your own in pure Python or using something like Yajl-Py.

Answer (score 1):

First you load the json and put it into a variable. Then what you do is add [9,10,11,12] to the list variabele:

```
list.append([9,10,11,12])
```

After that you rewrite the json file with the list variable

Comment: Yes I understand that this will be the easiest way for me to go do this. Will have to load it.